# split values of couch db result

Tags: gwt, couchdb

I want to split the values selected from couch db in gwt according to a particular id. I tried to use the String tokenizer but couldn't found something useful. the result returned from couch db is in the following format:

{"_id":"2","_rev":"1-717f76046030a683687ace9ac8f7bdbf","course":"jbdgjbj","passwd":"rty","phone":"24125514444","clgnme":"bjfbjf","address":"jbjfbjb","name":"meenal","cpasswd":"rty","user":"2","fname":"jfbg"}

I just want to get the values and set them in textboxes.

how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this ...

```
 Session studentDbSession = new Session("localhost",5984);

           Database studentCouchDb = studentDbSession.getDatabase("student");

           System.out.println("select");

           Document d = studentCouchDb.getDocument(input);
           if(d.containsKey("FirstName")){
               fname=d.getString("FirstName");//fname is variable
           }
           if(d.containsKey("LastName")){

               lname=d.getString("LastName");//lname is variable
           }
           if(d.containsKey("Address")){

               add= d.getString("Address");//add name is variable
           }
```

finally concatenate all strings and return to client...

```
       all=fname+" "+lname+" "+add;
       return all;
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON). You can parse it using [JSONObject](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html):

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(yourString);
String course = obj.getString("course");
```

Comment: Here is some JSON tutorial for gwt http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/tutorial/JSON.html and they use [com.google.gwt.json.client.JSONParser](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/json/client/JSONParser.html)